# bxslider controls not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

For some reason my bxslider will not work with controls (next/prev). I'm trying to create a page using the HTML-kickstarter and I have a full width bxslider. It works when using the settings it had when I downloaded it (with pager and autostart, after I switched from jquery 1.9.1 to 1.8.2) but when I change kickstart.js to get controls without autostart and without the pager it stops working.

I'm seeing the next/prev buttons and in developer tools everything seems fine but the next/prev buttons are not even showing up as links!

Could this have something to do with my html/css (navigation??) and possibly with the fact I'm building this on google drive??

[this would be the page I'm working on](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwpoLmzbt5awVTNWallYQ0FqSlU/blank.html#)

Thanks in advance
Tino

second edit:
fixed it :) It was just a question of layering div's

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you are working on or create a JSfiddle so we can see your code? There could be so many reasons why the controls do not work

Comment: edited the question, included link

Comment: your slideer is working (Prev/Next buttom) for me in Chrome which browser you are using?

Comment: also using chrome, but got it solved like 2 minutes before you commented :) I changed the z-indexes (indices??) and now the prev/next buttons are on top. Stackoverflow will not allow me to accept my own answer yet

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it. It was just a question of adjusting the z-indexes in my css. Which makes me  realize I have to research that a bit more because the next/prev buttons already had a z-index of 9999 which led me to believe it should have been on top already. Turns out I was wrong.